# C++ Linking error within projects having different character set

Tags: c++, character-encoding, exe

I am having linking error while compiling my C++ project Solution in VS 2005. Following is the scenario.

I have a solutions lets say `MySolution` within which there are 2 projects named

`MyTestLib` is a Static Library type project with Character Set `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` and with no `CLR` support

and

`MyTestApp` is a .exe app using the above lib with Character Set `Use Unicode Character Set` and with `CLR` support

in `MyTestLib` there are two overloaded functions with following definitions

```
int Class1::test1(int a)
{
    return a+4; 
}

bool Class1::test1(LPCTSTR param)
{
    return true;
}
```

`MyTestApp` is calling them from its code like

```
Class1 objcl1;
int a = objcl1.test1(12); //Works fine

Class1 objcl2;
string abc = "adsad";
bool t = objcl2.test1(abc.c_str()); //Error
```

calling the `test1(LPCTSTR)` version gives error

`Error  1   error C2664: 'int TestLib::Class1::test1(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'int'`

if I change the statement as `bool t = objcl2.test1((LPCTSTR)abc.c_str()); //Now linking Error`
Then I get

`Error  2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall TestLib::Class1::test1(wchar_t const *)" (?test1@Class1@TestLib@@$$FQAE_NPB_W@Z) TestProject.obj`

but if I change the project `MyTestApp` Character Set to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` then all the errors are resolved. But I can't change the project Character Set, as there are other dependencies.

Is there any work arround?

Comment: You might need to use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg tried this but its still giving linking error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that when you build `MyTestLib` this signature:

```
bool Class1::test1(LPCTSTR param);
```

Becomes

```
bool Class1::test1(const char * param);
```

Because `LPCTSTR` is a macro that is set depending on the "Character Set" configuration in place when the build occurs.

Now, when you build `MyTestApp` with the "Character Set" configured for UNICODE, it sees that function signature (from a header file, I assume) as:

```
bool Class1::test1(wchar_t const * param);
```

So the linker has no hope of linking that function to what's actually in the library.

The workaround is to simply not use `LPTCSTR` as the type for the function - the type of that parameter in the implemented function will always be `const char*`, so just say so in the function declaration.

Comment: and probably make two versions of the function, one taking char*, and one taking wchar_t*

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my time. `const char *` worked for me.